# See all my ListView items that added one by one and not all of them at the end

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

So i have this collections:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary;
ObservableCollection<MyItem> list = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();

public class MyItem
{
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public int Packets { get; set; }
    public decimal Percent { get; set; }
}
```

Here i am populate my `ListView`:

```
   foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in dictionary.OrderByDescending(value => value.Value))
    {
        double value = ((double)item.Value / someValue) * 100;
        MyItem myItem = new MyItem { IP = item.Key, Packets = item.Value, Percent = value };
        list.Add(myItem);
        listView.ItemsSource = list;
    }
```

So all i want is to see of my items one by one added, the current state is that i can see only at the end my `ListView` with all the item at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior : when you set the `ItemSource` with the ObservableCollection or if you set the ObservableCollection property after you added your items.

To do waht you expect you must set the item source before adding your items.

The ideal would be to bind the ItemSource to your ObservableCollection and then in your view model, fill your observable collection.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace StackOverflow2
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    readonly Dictionary<string, int> _dictionary;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        List = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
        _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        //bogus initial dictionary fill
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            _dictionary.Add("Key_"+i,i+1);
        }
    }

    private int someValue = 10;
    public void Fillcollection()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in _dictionary.OrderByDescending(value => value.Value))
            {
                decimal value = ((decimal)item.Value / someValue) * 100;
                MyItem myItem = new MyItem { IP = item.Key, Packets = item.Value, Percent = value };

                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>List.Insert(0,myItem));

                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> List { get; set; }
    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Fillcollection();
    }
}

public class MyItem
{
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public int Packets { get; set; }
    public decimal Percent { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:MainWindow}}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Content="FillCollection" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" ></Button>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding List}" Grid.Column="1" AutoGenerateColumns="True"></DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: + 1 for explanation
But this solution will not resolve problem.
Berry wants visualization of populating :)
He needs for timer

Comment: Well, indeed, if the process preceeding the add to your list is fast and that you have few items, the collection fills itself so fast that it seems that it is filled with one shot. I modified my sample to simulate long data treatment in background and I can assure you that you WILL see your items being added one at a time...